# How do I "access" shipping options from a custom module's controller?

Tags: module, shipping

I've created a module to programmatically create orders on Magento CE 1.9.2.2. Everything works perfectly fine in a workbench testing script but when I attempt to execute the same code from a custom controller, it breaks when trying to set shipping method (i.e. freeshipping). The free shipping option is enabled in Magento but I feel like I should be doing something differently.

Here is my controller's class & indexAction:

```
<?php

class MyCompany_Api_OrderController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

  public function indexAction()
  {
      $storeId = 1;

  $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
  ->setStoreId($storeId);

  $quote->setCustomerEmail('thecustomer@example.com');

  // add product(s)
  $product_sku = 'SKU1234'; // use your own sku number
  echo "Product SKU: " . $product_sku . "\n";
  $product_id = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku( $product_sku );
  echo "Product ID: " . $product_id . "\n";
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

  $params = array();

  $params['qty'] = 1;
  $request = new Varien_Object();
  $request->setData($params);

  $price = "19";
  $quoteItem = $quote->addProduct($product, $request);
  $quoteItem->setCustomPrice($price);
  $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);

  $addressData = array(
    'firstname' => 'John',
    'lastname' => 'Doe',
    'street' => 'Sample Street 10',
    'city' => 'Somewhere',
    'postcode' => '123456',
    'telephone' => '123456',
    'country_id' => 'US',
    'region_id' => 12, // id from directory_country_region table
  );

  $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
  $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);

  $shippingAddress->setFreeShipping( true )
  ->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
  ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping')
  ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');

  $quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));

  $quote->collectTotals()->save();
  $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
  $service->submitAll();
  $order = $service->getOrder();
  printf("Created order %s\n", $order->getIncrementId());
  }
}
```

The only difference between this and my workbench script is that I've removed the necessary 2 lines for workbenching:

```
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
```

I believe I need to use **Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getAllCarriers** somewhere before I attempt to call shipping methods but not certain. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. It appears that when selecting shipping methods, you need the module name and method. Like this:

```
      ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')
```